# Вывести одно значение по всем строкам, если хотя бы одно из значений столбца N равно 'abde'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно написать условие, которое выводит значение в соответствии с условием, в разрезе по каждому уникальному ID:

- Если хотябы одно из значений поля `pars` равно `abde`, то по всем строкам для этого ID вывести **abde**
- Если поле `pars` НЕ имеет значение `abde`, но имеет значение `s`, то вывести **s**
- Если в поле `pars` НЕ найдено значений `abde` или `s`, то **Null**

| id | pars | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 115465 | abde | abde |
| 115465 | s | abde |
| 115465 | null | abde |
| 28785 | s | s |
| 28785 | m | s |
| 49 | wow | null |

Answer (score 1):

По идее, высказанной @CrazyElf, но через оконные функции

```
select *
  ,case when sum(case when pars='abde' then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by id)>0 
          then 'abde'
        when sum(case when pars='s' then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by id)>0 
          then 's'
   else null -- это необязательно, но понятнее
   end new_value
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как это решается оптимально, но вроде можно было бы так:

- делаем выборку из таблицы и формируем через `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN 1 as flag1` поле со значением 1 где выполняется первое условие
- тоже самое для второго условия
- делаем поверх вышеуказанной выборки селект с группировкой по `ID` и вычислением `SUM(flag1), SUM(flag2)`
- делаем на том же уровне проверку этих сумм > 0 через тот же `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ...`, формируя поле с требуемыми значениями на выходе
- делаем `SELECT` из нашей таблицы и `JOIN` к ней результата вышеописанных манипуляций по `ID`